# shell script file for change directory

Tags: shell, scripting, osx-yosemite

I want to create package installer for refectorer i am using packages version 1.1.3 ,after copying the  refectorer files to the current machine I need to open terminal and change directory to the  refectorer folder and run make file so I need shell script file to do this i tried a lot using (cd) command but its not changing the directroy...anyone can help!!! this is my code

```
#!/bin/sh

osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate' -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down'

cd /Users/MacBookAir/Desktop/refactorerl-0.9.14.09

make
```

Comment: When you run a shell script it runs in its own shell. Any `cd` that occurs inside the shell script is relative to that shell. When the shell exits, you're back where you were. If you want to run your script in the *current* shell, run it this way at the command prompt: `. myscript` (use dot `.`).

Comment: That script should work just fine to run `make` from that directory. It won't affect the shell that ran the script though. If you need that then you need to do what lurker said. Is this not working correctly?

Comment: thx guys for naswer I know its working in Terminal by using (./myscript.sh) but problem is that when I attach this file to my packge that will copy and build the refactorerl the script is opening a new Terminal but not changing the directory and run the (make)...I want to attache this script file to my packge so after copying the refactorerl file to be able to build the refactorerl tool by runung this script...